# font path in css file of a codeigniter app on Azure shows 404?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, azure

I"m running my PHP codeigniter app on Azure.

In my css, I have set the font path as bellow

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Sample1-Light;
    src: url('../fonts/Sample1/Sample1-Light.otf');
}
```

Above code works well on my local host but once I put it on Azure, it shows me  404 error

```
http://samplewebsite1.azurewebsites.net/Helloworld/assets/fonts/Sample1/Sample1-Light.otf 404 (Not Found)
```

my 'fonts' folder is in the assets folder ('assets/fonts') and css file is inside in css folder which is at assets folder( 'assets/css' ).

Comment: So what would be the correct URL that would make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `web.config` file if not exists in the root of your app and put the following into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```